# Explain built in User model and UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I understand that django comes with a `User` model built in and the following code works and properly saves a user to the db, I just don't understand *why* it works:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import UserCreationForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Saved')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'form':form})
```

what is the line `form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)` saying? is the `(request.POST)` the contents of the submitted form? and how does `user = form.save()` save a user to the database? I was thinking that maybe the variable had to be named `user` for django to recognize it as a `User` object but this is not the case as I changed the statement to                 `test = form.save()`
and it still saved a `User` to my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The line form = UserCreationForm(request.POST) talks of itself actually. It posts data passed through your form to the variable form
2. The 'request' object is an HttpRequest object that carries metadata about the request (for example in our case, we have a post request , and the request object carries the user data). Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/) for more details.
3. Yes, user = form.save() saves a User instance in the database. UserCreationForm has a function called save() and here we're just calling that function.
4. The name of the variable has nothing to do with it because in the UserCreationForm's definition, the model is already defined as User. So, it already recognizes that it's the User model.

I this you should read the [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/) code to make things clear in your head.

Answer (score 0):

This is django doc :

```
[docs]class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
}
password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

You can see the "save" method, it use user model with super. Result UserCreationForm use User model and can save in User database